# Makefile conditional not respecting target-specific variables

Tags: makefile

Is there a way to use the native Makefile if-else conditional and also have it respects target-specific variables re-assignments?

**Example Makefile:**

```
#!/usr/bin/make

CONFIG = Debug

.PHONY: test printme

test: override CONFIG=Release
test: printme
    @echo "Done."

printme:
ifeq "$(CONFIG)" "Debug"
    @echo "should be DEBUG -> $(CONFIG)"
else
    @echo "should be RELEASE -> $(CONFIG)"
endif
```

Running `make test` prints the following output:

```
should be DEBUG -> Release
Done.
```

The output I'm looking for is `should be RELEASE -> Release` how can I achieve that? Do I need to use shell conditionals instead?

Comment: Makefile conditionals are always interpreted _when the makefile is parsed_.  Target-specific variables are only set _when the recipe is invoked_.  It's fundamentally impossible for `ifeq` to take into account target-specific variables as they don't exist when `ifeq` is parsed.  You have to either use shell conditionals, or the `$(if ...)` function inside your recipe.

Answer (score 3):

This behavior seems logical to me: At the time of parsing the Makefile, `CONFIG` is defined as `Debug`. The `ifeq` conditional uses the value of `CONFIG` it knows at that time. Therefore it chooses the `ifeq` branch that outputs "Should be DEBUG".

The target-specific variable is only defined as `Release` with the target `test`. Its prerequisite `printme` also knows the target-specific variable and ouputs `Release`.

---

May I suggest that you set variable to `make` on the command line for the purpose you want. It's not many more characters to write when invoking `make` but brings all you seem to be willing.

```
make CONFIG=Release
```